# Cannot post to mysql variable added lines

Tags: php, mysql

Can't quite figure this one out. Not posting to MySQL. Not getting errors, just not posting.

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","XXXX","XXXX");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  } 
mysql_select_db("XXXX", $con); 
for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ )
  {
    $newtest1 = $_POST['test1'.$i];
    $newtest2 = $_POST['test2'.$i];
    $newtest3 = $_POST['test3'.$i];
  }
    $sql="INSERT INTO database (test1,test2,test3) VALUES ('".$newtest1."','".$newtest2."','".$newtest3."')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
?>
```

Tried `('$_POST[test1]')` and `(' . $_POST['test1'.$i] . ')`

Comment: If you know there are 3 items then why are using loop, the value will be lost in each loop. For example i=1 will get newetest1 ... etc but in i=2 previous values will be lost. U can put the query inside the loop if you want to add then in each loop, so that ur data remains before the loop goes to next level

Comment: What type of field is `test1`?

Comment: Where is $count being defined?  If it's not, you're just running an endless for loop and you'll never run the actual query

Comment: You should read up on sql injection.

Comment: what are you using to post? a form? Like @AbhikChakraborty said, this isn't the right place for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO database (test1,test2,test3) VALUES ('".$newtest1."','".$newtest2."','".$newtest3."')";
```

Here there is a "table" which you want to insert a data.

You may get the idea of using $sql wrong.

I'll try to explain it from an example photo: [PHOTO](http://imageshack.com/a/img822/2272/w14j.png)

As you see i have a database called "test" and a table in it which im inserting my data.

You should use this code and connect to that database:

```
mysql_select_db("XXXX", $con); //to select "my" database (on the example) type "test" to "XXXX"
```

The "database" you wrote here:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO database (test1,test2,test3) VALUES ('".$newtest1."','".$newtest2."','".$newtest3."')";
```

must be changed to your selected database. In this case you just wrote "XXXX" to that.

So the final code is:

$sql="INSERT INTO XXXX (test1,test2,test3) VALUES ('".$newtest1."','".$newtest2."','".$newtest3."')";